# How to return TEXT value after x number of rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I know how to return this for numbers but I'm getting an error when I use the formula for text values.

Example:

Number A
Number B
Number C
Number D
Number E

So I want to return the following

Number A, Number C and Number E

using a formula.
How can I go about this?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 1):

Use `query`'s skipping:

```
=query(A2:A6,"skipping 2")
```